# SHA-1 - Your operation was forbidden. Firebase SHA-1 error

Tags: firebase, sha1

I have two firebase projects on separate accounts. I have two android projects, one is for test and one is for production.

The SHA-1 key generated is the same, it works in the first firebase project which is on the other account, but when I try and put it in the production account and project. It gives the Your operation is forbidden error.

I've then gone and deleted the SHA-1 key from the test project, but I still get the same error.

What could be the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around, I seemed to have found a way around this myself.

I deleted debug.keystore and then rebuild the project. After that I generated the signing report, the signing report generates a new SHA-1 key which was then accepted by Firebase